# Java: List initialization with Generics (T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface)

Tags: java, generics, collections, enums

im still quite weak in using generics and im having a question:
Based on the following method i would like to initalize a list:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface> boolean getIsDescSort(Class<T> tableSortEnum) {
        return tableSortEnum.getName().endsWith(DESC_SUFFIX);
}
```

Is it (in general) possible to initialize a List exactly with these kinds of objects? Or in other words: Can i type my list with these informations? Enums which implement a certain interface?

```
List<T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface> myList;
```

shows me several errors in my Eclipse IDE so i assume it wouldn't compile.
I read some articles about this but don't get if this is even allowed/possible while initialze a collection...

Comment: "Isn't working" is about as helpful as if I were to answer you with "yes it's possible".

Comment: 'T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface' is an "intersection type". This is really advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to type at the wrong place. For example the following will work just fine

```
public class Foo<T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface> {
    private List<T> foo;
}
```

As will this

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & AnyInterface> List<T> foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList<T> foo = new ArrayList<>();
    return foo;
}
```